# Airflow Upgradedb Issue

Tags: airflow, devops, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to upgrade DB using the "airflow upgradedb" command on version 1.10.2. My question is what if the upgradedb is done for airflow version 1.10.2, and if the user wants to move back to version 1.9.0 and again performs upgradedb on the same database, then it has to fail due to alembic revision tags missing an issue.
Shouldn't there be a way saying that tables for version 1.9.0 is already available hence upgrade should successfully pass?
The reason why I am asking is my DB is already upgraded for version 1.10.2 when I was deploying airflow into EC2 but now am deploying airflow (version 1.8 to 1.9.0) into Kubernetes pods acting on the same database, it says revision tags "41f5f12752f8" are missing.